# Finding complete residue systems in Gaussian integers

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, gaussian-integers

Let $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ be the ring of Gaussian integers. A set $C\subset \mathbb{Z}[i]$ is called a complete residue system (CRS) modulo $\alpha$ if for every Gaussian integer $\pi$ there exists a unique $\rho \in C$ such that $\alpha$ divides $\pi - \rho.$ I intuitively see that one such system is the set of point enclosed by $\alpha, i \alpha$ , How do I exhibit explicitly such a set, say for $\alpha = 2 + 2i$, and prove that it is a CRS? In addition, how do I show that there are $N(\alpha)$ elements in this residue system? (with $N$ the usual norm on complex numbers.)

Comment: Is $\pi\in C$?  You mentioned $C$ once, but not again.

Comment: No, $\rho \in C.$ Fixed now, thanks

Comment: The notation $\pi$ is strange, like calling an integer $p$ when it is not necessarily prime. The concept of CRS looks a lot more reasonable if you describe it by the condition $\pi \equiv \rho \bmod \alpha$ instead of $\alpha \mid (\pi - \rho)$. (Do you think $m \mid (a-b)$ is a more natural idea than $a \equiv b \bmod m$?)  Anyway, Section 7 of https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/ugradnumthy/Zinotes.pdf addresses your question (see Theorem 7.14).